# Capture windows cmd prompt execution?

Tags: windows-8

Occasionally (one/two times a day), on my Win 8.1 PC there's a cmd prompt popping up for about 0.1 sec, and closes automatically. It's scary, and I wonder if there's a way to capture who's doing it (and what does it do)?

The ESET scan hadn't found anything, as well as EMET. For some reason I suspect it's some intel driver, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

A similar thread was discussed a couple of days ago. Hope it's of help for you. If not let me know. https://superuser.com/questions/1213475/console-window-keeps-popping-up

Comment: Seems to be the same topic. Can you flag it as a duplicate?

Comment: Hm, I don't like where that thread is headed - they're discussing a particular issue, i.e. if you know what's popping up the cmd prompts than it's problem solved. I'd like to know if it would be possible to find out what it is in the first place? Like, for instance, replacing `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` with an exe of my own, that (after logging) passes it's parameters to the original cmd... would something like that work?